# How to edit the first line of XYZ file?

Tags: molecular-modeling, python, software-input-file-request

```
114

Ge 11.184091389011632 8.1000459052469 7.912778504608498 0.7601333333333333
Ge 8.15544869153235 6.003103511684641 4.013838014930662 0.7568333333333334
Ge 9.485968612508206 8.750636482182767 3.89712476883384 0.5934333333333334
....
```

I want to change the number of atoms, preferably using Python where it will automatically find the number atom. Such as here, we have 8 atoms but it shows 114. Any lead how to do this edit automatically for different input files.

Comment: Please show the full xyz file. This has only 3 atoms, not 8. Also it has 4 columns of numbers rather than 3 (x,y,z). You want a program that takes an xyz file, and based on the number of rows representing atoms, puts the correct number at the top?

Comment: Using bash script for these kind of tasks should be a lot easier. This can be done with bash by: ```nlines=`wc -l test.xyz | awk '{print $1}'`; natoms=$((nlines-2)); sed -i "1s/.*/$natoms/" test.xyz```

Comment: It seems that this question, with a little rephrasing, might find better and more numerous answers on a SE specifically dedicated to coding. It involves no specific molecular modeling knowledge and could be easily described as a generic coding problem

Comment: @Saha_1994, Is there a problem with your .xyz file?

Comment: @BarbaudJulien I disagree with this statement. Matter modeling SE is all matters modeling, which includes computer programming. If you seek to understand more about the chemistry of the topic then I might suggest Chemistry SE. However, only if you have a fundamental and obscure computer programming question, or if the question isn’t receiving enough attention would I recommend SO.

Comment: @RashidRafeek why not write that solution up, as an answer?

Comment: @Cody Aldaz noted. I was not trying to say that this is unfit for here btw, just that he is likely to get faster (and maybe better) answers by reformulating it as a coding problem and submitting on more populated coding SEs

Comment: @NikeDattani Yeah, I should have. Earlier I misread the question as to asking for python script specifically and now only noticed that the OP only prefers a python solution. Anyway, the logic of my script is now in an answer below by Prasanta, so maybe no need to have a duplicate answer?

Comment: @RashidRafeek if the logic is the same but the answer is different, I still think it would be a valuable contribution to the site!

Comment: @NikeDattani Done!

Comment: Assuming you use linux, a bash command such as `sed -i '1c\NumAtoms' file` would change the first line to NumAtoms very easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this by just modifying the first line of the file.

But here are some more general purpose utilities you could use (note it requires the `re` module)

```py
def read_xyz(
    filename, 
    scale=1.):

    """ Read xyz file

    Params:
        filename (str) - name of xyz file to read

    Returns:
        geom ((natoms,4) np.ndarray) - system geometry (atom symbol, x,y,z)

    """
    
    lines = open(filename).readlines()
    lines = lines[2:]
    geom = []
    for line in lines:
        mobj = re.match(r'^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$', line)
        geom.append((
            mobj.group(1),
            scale*float(mobj.group(2)),
            scale*float(mobj.group(3)),
            scale*float(mobj.group(4)),
            ))
    return geom
```

```py
def write_xyz(
    filename, 
    geom, 
    comment=0,
    scale=1.0 #(1.0/units.ANGSTROM_TO_AU),
    ):

    """ Writes xyz file with single frame

    Params:
        filename (str) - name of xyz file to write
        geom ((natoms,4) np.ndarray) - system geometry (atom symbol, x,y,z)

    """
    fh = open(filename,'w')
    fh.write('%d\n' % len(geom))
    fh.write('{}\n'.format(comment))
    for atom in geom:
        fh.write('%-2s %14.6f %14.6f %14.6f\n' % (
            atom[0],
            scale*atom[1],
            scale*atom[2],
            scale*atom[3],
            ))
```

If you read the file and then write the file it will automatically save it with the correct number of atoms.

Comment: isn't using regex a little overkill when you could just do `line.split()`?

Comment: I'd recommend the `line.split()` version. I'd also point out that this particular file includes what I suspect are partial charges in the last column, and the poster may want to preserve that.

Answer (score 3):

More a comment than an answer, note that e.g., for methane

```
5

C          0.92745       -0.05402        0.04264
H          2.01965       -0.05402        0.04264
H          0.56338        0.81142        0.60065
H          0.56338       -0.96998        0.51313
H          0.56338       -0.00348       -0.98585
```

the first line including `5` (in this example) announces how many atoms will follow *past* the second line which may be used for comments (like the name of structure/molecular weight as a label-like e.g., [OpenBabel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel) does).  Thus keep this integer consistent with the content.

Answer (score 3):

It should be easy to achieve what you want with a bash script. For a file named `test.xyz`, it can be achieved with:

```bash
fname=test.xyz
nlines=`wc -l $fname | awk '{print $1}'`
natoms=$((nlines-2))
sed -i "1s/.*/$natoms/" $fname
```

This follows the logic given in the answer by @Prasanta. It should be easy to change this to a script taking the filename as input so that you can do the same with many input files.

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange type question. First, there is something wrong with the xyz file having total 5 columns.
For you answer,

1. Find total row number (let it be r)
2. calculate r-2 (since the format of the xyz is that after the total number of atoms, there is a gap followed by atomic coordinates. The end of atomic coordinate specifications ends the file)
3. replace first line(row) with r-2 value.

You either do it with bash or python you like.

Comment: There are plenty of "extensions" to XYZ through adding extra columns. If I had to guess, this is "symbol, x, y, z, partial charge" which is one of the more common variants.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not have any idea about that.